NextAuth: Remember Me functionality
I would like to implement a remember-me functionality.
I decided to use the JWT cookies to be stored in order to login the user, however I encounter the issue that I cannot change the expiry date to a short time, or even better, store it in a local storage to make sure it is deleted once the user leaves the website.
auth.config.ts
import { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";

export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
    signOut: '/'
  }, 
  jwt: {
    maxAge: 60*60*1
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
      const isOnDashboard = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard');
      const isOnSettings = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/settings')
      if (isOnDashboard || isOnSettings) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true;
        return false; // Redirect unauthenticated users to login page
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', nextUrl));
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
  providers: [], // Add providers with an empty array for now
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

auth.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { authConfig } from './auth.config';
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { z } from 'zod';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { getUser } from '@/app/libs/dbCore';


export const { auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
    ...authConfig,

    providers: [
      Credentials({
        async authorize(credentials) {
          const parsedCredentials = z
            .object({ email: z.string().email(), password: z.string().min(6) })
            .safeParse(credentials);
   
          if (parsedCredentials.success) {
            const { email, password } = parsedCredentials.data;
            const user = await getUser(email);
            if (!user) return null;

            const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
            // Update lastActive DB
            // Log creation
            if (passwordsMatch) return user;
          }

          console.log('Invalid credentials');
          return null;
        },
      }),
    ],
  });

What is the best approach regarding NextAuth and Remember me feature?
I tried to change the maxAge, restart the server, but nothing is taken into consideration. I don't even see a way to set it in the local storage within NextAuth documentation

I am stuck with the same problem, did you find any solution yet?
